# No battery icon in Ubuntu Gnome 14.04

Tags: gnome, icons, asus, battery, 14.04

I'm using an Asus K56CB Laptop and I just upgraded from Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 to Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 (Gnome shell 3.10.4) however now I don't have a battery icon in the upper right-hand corner. Also the brightness slider is also missing. (see screen shot)

The battery and power management is present and working (I can go into power in the setting panel and it detects my battery and tells the level of charge) I don't think it's an ACPI problem.

Things i've tired from search around the forums:

Setting `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power.active = true` (did this via dconf-editor) It was already set to active

I've also tried to re-install gnome-power-management.

Thanks for any help !

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Because I can't comment to correct a link without an appropriately leveled reputation, I have to post this as an answer. Steveowashere found the solution to the problem via:
https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3-staging

Comment: I have the same problem.
have unity ////////
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power.active = true
the power indicator is installed. I have enabled energy option.
show battery status in the menu bar. some help thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to open energy manager in gnome-control-center and set all the options. In my case, behavior for critically low battery was in blank. Setting it to "close" makes power indicator to appear in both the panel and the popup-menu. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! But sadly it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. Battery icon and menu automatically appears in my laptop during charge and discharge. When battery is not used, the close session icon is shown instead... I got confused because i removed the power connector when i was tweaking gnome-control-center options :-)

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own problem by upgrading gnome shell to 3.12 using the PPA from this website: [Ubuntu Gnome Staging PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3-staging)

Comment: This webpage is not available.

Comment: @Aby, fixed the link there was a typo mistake in it. Steveowashere, could you accept your own answer as it is the one that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System Settings** select **power** then in **Show battery status in menu bar** change it to **when battery is present**.